# Torsion of a closed curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Why the total torsion of a closed curve on a sphere is zero? What is the meaning of total torsion? Is it mean that we should calculate the torsion from point A to point A  (i.e. since the curve is closed, we calculate the torsion from the start point to the start point)?

Comment: It means you integrate with respect to arc length along the curve. The result is false without the assumption of lying on a sphere, the example being torus knots, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_knot or electric wire wrapped around a torus to make an electromagnet called a solenoid.

Comment: Meanwhile, where did you find this? What book are you studying?